# Making n matrixes with repeating numbers

Tags: python, arrays, list, python-2.7

I am an new to Python (and programing in general) and wonder if someone could help me out with this one?

I want to make n (1*4) matrixes where the first one is:

```
[1,2,3,4],
```

and the next ones

```
[3,4,5,6],  

[5,6,7,8], 

[7,8,9,10]
```

and so on..

```
n=70
```

I have tried this so far but i only get the first 1 and 2 right, and then it repeats!

```
L2G = np.zeros((70,1,4))
for i in range(70):
    L2G[i,:,:] = [1,2,3,4]
    if L2G[i,0,0] == L2G[i-1,0,0]:
        L2G[i,:,:] += 2
```

Comment: "any clever code plz?" - StackOverflow is not a free code service. Have you tried anything?

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? You won't learn how to program effectively if you keep relying on other people's back for free code.

Comment: "StackOverflow is not a free code service!" Yes i know this isnt a free "code supermarked", and i forgot to mention that I have been trying several things but I am to new with this to post some stupid code that is way off! Anyway, i tried to first make list = zeros((70,1,4)) # then to assign the numbers to each layer. But then I got stuck!

Comment: @user2734012 I like comprehensions with a slice. [[x+2,x+3,x+4,x+5] for x in range(-1,139)][::2] [List Comprehensions 5.1.4](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possibility:

```
>>> n = 4
>>> result = np.arange(1,5) + 2*np.arange(n)[:,None]
>>> result
array([[ 1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 3,  4,  5,  6],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8],
       [ 7,  8,  9, 10]])
```

This works because of how `numpy` [broadcasting](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html#general-broadcasting-rules) behaves.  You can add the one-dimensional array

```
>>> np.arange(1,4+1)
array([1, 2, 3, 4])
```

to the 2-d array

```
>>> 2*np.arange(n)[:,None]
array([[0],
       [2],
       [4],
       [6]])
```

to produce the desired result.

Note though that this is one object, like your `L2G`, not `n` separate objects, and is an `array`, not a `matrix`.

Comment: Excelent,thanks a lot! This is excactly what i wanted. cheers!